# Compilation error when trying to use variadic parameters with subscript in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

From the Swift 2.0 book, it says that

> “Subscripts can use variable parameters and variadic parameters”

I'm trying to implement a simple class that uses variadic parameters in a subscript, but I'm running into a compilation error.

```
class ClassWithSubscript {
    var values = [String: String]()

    subscript(fields: String...) -> String? {
        get {
            return values[fields[0]]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            values[fields[0]] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

The compilation error is `<unknown>:0: error: result type '@lvalue String?' (aka '@lvalue Optional<String>') does not match expected type`

I'm using Xcode 7 GM Seed (7.0 7A218)

Looks like removing the setter allows compilation to succeed. Any way I can get it to compile without removing the setter?

I made [a post in the Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/53661) on this topic as well.

EDIT: I've filed a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be considered a bug.

If you remove the variadic parameter and use `String` or `[String]` instead you can use the setter.

Another solution which probably doesn't work for you:

```
// using a separate set function:
func set(fields: String..., newValue: String) {
    values[fields[0]] = newValue
}
```

Comment: This is my thought as well, is there a way to report this to Apple? I've already posted in the dev forums